# Migrating Eclipse Android Junit Tests into Android Studio Gradle

Tags: eclipse, junit, gradle, android-studio

We are trying to migrate our Eclipse projects using ant builds into Android Studio using gradle.  So far all is good except for our JUnit tests that use external json files.  We have a ton of these where the the external file is located in the same directory as the java file.  Is there a way to keep the java code and the json file in the same location and just modify the build scripts in gradle?

Current build directory is something like this `\com\pack\krf\` contains `MyFileTest.java` and `data.json`.  Source code to load json is this:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("data.json");
```

I do not want to change 300+ java files that have this same structure.  Plus I do not want to group into the resource directory in gradle since some of these files will have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution one of my teammates came up with.  Add this to your build.gradle file after the android declaration.  The print path is for debugging.

```
task alterResourcePath << {
     sourceSets.testDebug.resources.srcDir('src/test/java')
     sourceSets.testDebug.resources.srcDirs.each {
     File f->
         if(f.exists()){
            println f.path
         }
     }
}

test.dependsOn alterResourcePath
```

Answer (score 1):

By default gradle (like Maven) puts the resources under `src/main/resources`, so you'll have to tell Gradle to look for them in `src/<something>/java` instead:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest {
            resources {
                srcDirs = ['src/instrumentTest/java']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you are running robolectric test you do the same, but the robolectric plugins out there uses standard java source sets. So you won't do this inside the Android extension:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        }
    }
}
```

If you use other sourceSets (per flavor or per build Type) you'll need to update those as well.

Comment: Doesn't work, I forgot to mention we are using RoboElectric but also want to use Robotium for UI tests

Comment: If you are using roboeletric you just do the same but for the roboelectric sourcesets. I'll edit my answer.